# Refreshing the macro library

Tags: macros, sas, sas-studio

I've been using a macro library so that I can use macros without compiling them first. The problem is that when I change the macro and save it, then refresh my filename for the macro lib, this is not enough to update and use the new macro?

Anyone have any ideas why it is still using and compiling the old macro before it was saved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first time a macro is called, if it hasn't already been defined, SAS will check your autocall path and iterate through those locations trying to find it.

When it finds the macro in your autocall library it compiles it and saves the compiled version to your work folder.  Subsequent calls to the macro will result in SAS using the compiled version of the macro.

In order for it to be refreshed (if you have made changes since it was compiled) you need to open the code to the macro and submit it again.  That will redefine/recompile it for you.

Alternatively, you could also find the catalog in your work folder that contains the compiled versions of the macros and delete it from there (typically `work.sasmacr`).

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Is there a way to delete that file?

Comment: Or even see it, trying to locate the file now but is not active so it says

Comment: found it, it seems to be there once I've compiled them

Answer (score 2):

Robert explains why you see the behavior.

I use the following to easily reinclude a changed macro.  This assumes you have a `FILENAME` called `MACROREF` defined to the folder in question.

```
%include MACROREF(my_macro);
```

Obviously change the `my_macro` to the macro you need to be compiled.

```
filename macroref "c:\temp";

%include MACROREF(MacroOne);
```

If you have a folder full of macros (as stated in the comments) you can include the whole folder.

```
%include "%sysfunc(pathname(MACROREF))/*.sas";
```

This will recompile the whole folder.  Just don't have any non-macro sas files in that folder, otherwise you are running them too.

Comment: I have too many macros to have to do this for each one, which is why I use the macro folder

Comment: I think the ideal solution is to clear the macro library mentioned above, appreciate the help